# C++ library to interface .dmg files on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I want to write a C++ program that spawns off a thread to execute a .dmg file and monitor its completion (success/fail) on Snow Leopard. Would this be as trivial as fork/exec a shell script on Linux? Would I need a 3rd party C++ library to interface .dmg files?

Comment: .dmg files are not executable, they are disk image files that you can mount, some what like an .iso file. They don't execute.

Comment: sorry, new to StackOverflow as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .dmg file on OS X is a container for an image of a volume or single file system so it's not clear what you mean by *execute a .dmg file*.  If you mean *mount the file systems contained in the .dmg file*, the easiest way to do that is with the [hdiutil](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) command:

```
hdiutil attach /path/to/file.dmg
```

If you need to parse the information about the file systems mounted, use the `-plist` argument which will return that information in OS X `plist` format via stdout.

Comment: Sorry, my first time developing on Mac. Our Mac installation package is a .dmg file, so I'm treating it like a .msi file, which is apparently fallacious.

So I'm guessing I need to mount the .dmg file first and then run the installer inside?

Comment: Correct, if there is an installer.  Apple recommends to avoid using installers, if possible.  If the product is a stand-alone .app, you can just ship the app on the dmg and users just copy it to their hard disk (usually to /Applications) with the Finder.  hdiutil can also be used to create .dmg files, btw.